# Unable to stop reading in Shell Script

Tags: bash

For a final project, I'm trying to create a shell script that will allow for easy user creation. The requirements include that I read information from a file and create a user based off of that. This is a snippet of code I'm having trouble with.

```
echo -n "Please provide a path to the file containing these parameters: "
read inputPath 

fileInfo = $(grep $inputPath) 

if [ -n "$fileInfo" ]; then 
    IFS="," read firstName lastName phoneNo emailAd < "$fileInfo" 
else
    echo "Cannot read, file is empty." >&2 
    exit 1
fi
```

After **read inputPath** It will not stop accepting input and continue onto the next line of code. I'm totally stumped.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work at all as an assignment statement:

```
fileInfo = $(grep $inputPath)
```

The shell does no allow spaces around `=` in an assignment.  Even with we fix that problem, we will still have another:

```
fileInfo=$(grep $inputPath)
```

If `inputPath` is a path with no spaces in it, then `grep` will look for that string in stdin and it will continue looking until you press ctrl-D to close stdin.

You demonstrate this by trying it at the command prompt:

```
$ inputPath=/usr/bin/python
$ grep $inputPath
```

The shell will wait for you to provide input.

Most likely, you wanted to search for something in the file whose name is `$inputPath`:

```
fileInfo=$(grep something "$inputPath")
```

Note that we have quoted `inputPath` to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

#### More on the command with spaces

Let's look at this again:

```
fileInfo = $(grep $inputPath)
```

If the shell sees this command, it will try to run the command `fileInfo` with first argument `=` and with the remaining arguments being the result of word splitting and pathname expansion on whatever `$(grep $inputPath)` produces.  But, to do this, as Jonathan Leffler points out in the comments, the shell must *first* run `grep $inputPath`. As long as `$inputPath` does not contain whitespace, then `grep` will read stdin looking for text that matches the value of `$inputPath`.  Unless ctrl-D is typed, the shell will appear to hang here.

In other words, even though the version of the command with the extra spaces has multiple problems, the *first* problem to be noticed will be that `grep` is waiting for stdin.

Comment: The other issue is with the *incomplete* grep expression. I see `grep` and i presume the regex is `$inputPath`, but then applied to what? (edit fixed it)

Comment: Note that the spaced out expression will 'run' but the `grep` will be run first, so the fact that there probably isn't a command called `fileInfo` isn't noticed — unless you type control-D to indicate EOF.  The `$(grep $inputPath)` is the primary cause of the trouble.  And basic [How to debug a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script/) technique would show that it was the `grep` and not the `read` causing trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is fascinating.  Answer updated with a discussion of that.